# using OleDB vs SqlServerCe

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, sql-server-ce, oledb

Looking for performance vs. ease of use comparisons between the two

Hopefully some real world examples too ?

This is for a desktop Winforms/C# app using SQL Server Compact 3.5 and .net 2.0

Comment: question does not make sense. What are you comparing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some guy did a benchmark of the 2 which you can find here http://www.pocketpcdn.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=11003